# Forest VS Jungle , when to use them?

Tags: word-choice

What is the real differnce between `Forest` and `Jungle` , Is there any specific usage for this words ?

From [Here](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-forest-and-jungle):

> The definitions clearly state that a jungle is a type of forest. It
>   just differs in the density. A jungle is a dense and impenetrable
>   forest or a part of a forest.

But I dont clearly understand what is this saying , I mean when I should call a couple of trees a `Jungle` and when `Forest`?

Comment: Hi Arman. Welcome to ELL. What have you found out about these words in dictionaries? We expect you to check the meanings of those words first, and tell us what you know, then tell us what questions you still might have. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Helpful links: [Jungle](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/forest-jungle-wood-woods.186539/) and [Forest](http://www.ehow.com/info_8377449_differences-woods-forests-jungles.html) and [size of forest](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100608195506AAc91JX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would generally not call a "couple of trees" a jungle or a forest. Those terms indicate a larger area. Jungles are normally in hot areas in the tropics, or are very thick forests.

See, for example, [this definition of jungle listed on dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jungle?s=t).

Comment: So , Jungle and Forest are for very big scales?

Comment: Normally, yes. Jungles and forests are large areas.

Comment: Is there any specifc word for a couple of trees in small area ?

Comment: Take a look at NOUN, #6 for *stand* here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stand

Comment: @Arman: *copse*, *grove*, *stand* come to mind for a *cluster of trees*.

Comment: A **stand** of *a particular type of tree* may occur within a larger forest

Comment: Frankly, if we are talking about just two or three trees, most English speakers would say, "some trees". I think "stand" is typically used when the trees are all the same type, like "a stand of elm trees" -- but checking a couple of dictionaries they all just say a "group of trees".

Comment: Good point, Jay. We can't be sure what the OP wants to describe. The best for a couple of trees might be *a couple of trees!* Or *a small cluster of trees.* Arman can search google images for some of the terms and see if one of the terms suggested seems to fit.

Comment: *jungles* tend to have lots of wild animals (lions, tigers, etc.). *Forests* tend to have deer and furry creatures.

Comment: For some reason, I usually think of pines when I hear _forest_, and palms when I hear _jungle_. Put in pictures, I imagine a "forest" to look like [this](http://ncbeautiful.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/forest-trees-4sp.jpg), and a "jungle" to look like [this](http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/banana-trees-in-jungle-sami-sarkis.jpg). (Obviously, that's oversimplified, but it's still a distinction that springs to mind.) Jungles tend to be more lavish and green.